# compare two dates using compare validator

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to compare two date textboxes to make sure one date is greater than the other. I am getting errtatic response where it is rejecting this rule eventhough the date is greater. Anything wrong with this code? Here is my definition

```
 <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ControlToCompare="txtStDt" ControlToValidate="txtEdDt" 
                    ErrorMessage="End date must be later than the start date!" 
                    Operator="GreaterThan" Type="Date"  ValidationGroup="VG1">  
 </asp:CompareValidator>
```

The date format I'm using with the calendar extender in both the dates' textboxes is 'dd/MMM/yyyy'. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add this at the start of your page and try and compare to see if you get correct results

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false"
  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" Culture="en-GB" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends your date format. Your code only works with UK date fomat. [Here](http://geekswithblogs.net/ptahiliani/archive/2009/07/04/how-to-use-compare-validator-with-ddmmyyyy-format-of-date.aspx) is some example of this.